# I'm trying to upload images through angular to asp.net rest api i'm facing that error 'Incorrect Content-Type:application/json'

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload images through Angular to ASP.NET REST API,I'm facing that error "System.InvalidOperationException: `Incorrect Content-Type:application/json` in controller's class at the line Request.Form.Files. How I can solve that error?

**It's ASP.NET REST API side data**

**It's model class for receiving image data from ui**

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
}
```

---

**It's entity class for db**

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Contents { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Controller's class**

```
public IActionResult PostAdv(AdvModel model)
{
    try
    {
        Advertisement entity = new Advertisement();
        entity.Id = model.Id;
        entity.Name = model.Name;
        entity.Price = model.Price;
        entity.Description = model.Description;
                
        foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(ms);
                    entity.Images.Add(new Image { Contents = ms.ToArray() });
                }
            }
        }

                new AdvHandler().PostAdv(entity);

                return Created(Request.Path, entity.ToModel());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ex); //Internal server error;

    }
}
```

---

**It's angular side data**

**Image model's class**

```
export interface Images {
    id: number,
    contents: string
}
```

---

**Component**

```
export class PostAdvComponent implements OnInit {

  advForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() adv: Advertisement;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private advService: AdvService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.advForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      name: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      images: this.fb.array([
        this.addImages()
      ])
    });
  }  
  addImages(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      contents: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  uploadImage(event: any) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const file = files[i];

      const reader = new FileReader();
      
      //reader.readAsBinaryString(file); 
      reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
      reader.onload = (event) => {
        //const base64String = reader.result?.toString().split(',')[i];
        const base64String = reader.result as string;
        //const binaryString = event.target?.result?.toString().split(',')[i];

        //const regex = /[^A-Za-z0-9+-/="]/g;
        //const regex = /[+-/="]/g;
        const cleanedBase64String = base64String.replace(/[-="]/g, '');
        this.advForm.patchValue({
          contents: cleanedBase64String
        })
      }
    }

  addAdvertisement() {
    this.mapFormValuesToAdvModel();
    console.log(this.advForm);
    
    this.advService.postAdv(this.adv)
      .subscribe(add => {
        console.log(add);
      });
}
  mapFormValuesToAdvModel() {
    this.adv.name = this.advForm.value.name;
    this.adv.price = this.advForm.value.price;
    this.adv.description = this.advForm.value.description;
    this.adv.images = this.advForm.value.images;
  }
}

// I tried to convert images data into base64 string and send it to rest api
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you don't attach any image to form directly and you store them in `ImageModel`.

```
public IActionResult PostAdv(AdvModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var entity = new Advertisement()
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Name = model.Name,
            Price = model.Price,
            Description = model.Description
        };
        
        foreach (var image in model.Images)
        {
            if (image.Contents.Length == 0) continue;

            var convertedContents = image.Contents.Replace('-', '+');
            convertedContents = convertedContents.Replace('_', '/');
            
            var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(convertedContents);
            entity.Images.Add(new Image
            {
                Contents = imageBytes
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ex); //Internal server error;
    }
}
```

Comment: i follow your method & i'm getting that error on that line 'var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image.Contents);'  System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'

Comment: Sorry, i forget to write that line, i'm not storing it into model, i'm converting it into entity object and sending it to db.

Comment: Okay. I see. Are you store your image as base64 string? If yes you save images' data into `Advertisement.Images` collection? @JuniorDev

Comment: its how i declare images collection property in AdvModel class "public  ICollection<ImageModel> Images { get; set; }"...its normal string property in model class and in entity which is for db here it's byte[] type property as you can see above on the top Imagemodel class and for entity its image class

Comment: Is it UTF8 string and on server you convert UTF8 to bytes? Or it is Base64 string?

Comment: not its simple string property of c# in which i'm trying to receive image data from angular and i don't know that how i can receive image data from angular. before that when i were  used razor pages mvc it was working fine for images

Comment: By using memory stream i am converting it into byte array then i send it to db

Comment: Try to enter `base64String` from your Angular app directly into the form. Maybe it throws such error because your code removes critical characters.
`const cleanedBase64String = base64String.replace(/[-="]/g, '');`

Comment: Yes i already did that but its giving error,before going to replace these special characters i was sending it by using that line "const base64String = reader.result?.toString().split(',')[i];"

Comment: Did you try a modified solution?

Comment: yes i already did that.i want to tell u that when i post data from angular to controller in AdvModel in images object i received in contents property that data "C:\\fakepath\\2.jfif"..its not a base64 string.what i have to do?